# Eliminar carpeta de archivos de la rama máster

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-add

una consulta: estaba intentando subir una carpeta con varios archivos a mi repositorio github, y digamos que comencé ejecutando varios comando según un vídeo encontrado, los comando van en el siguiente orden:

```
Git init
```

Dentro de mi carpeta llamada Java-Proyect posteriormente hice:

```
Git remote ....
```

En dicha carpeta, posteriormente moví mi carpeta ListasSimoles de NetBeans proyect a mi carpeta Java-Proyect que está conectada a mi git remoto, para hacer el respectivo commit; comencé con el comando:

```
Git add .
```

Seguido de

```
Git commit -m "prueba"
```

Y finalmente hice el:

```
Git push ....
```

Todo esto basado en el vídeo, pero resulta que cuando voy a mi carpeta remota en github me no me aparece tal carpeta sino un mensaje llamado máster.... Al ingresar en la palabra máster me aparece la carpeta ListaSimple con todo los archivos, pero no en la carpeta remota, es decir: mi repositorio donde está la carpeta remota: Java-Proyect está ubicada en:

Htttps://github.com/minombre/Java-Proyect pero mi carpeta con los commit está en Htttps://github.com/minombre/Java-Proyect/tree/máster

La pregunta es cómo elimino la carpeta ListaSimple y su info que está en máster y la guardo en la otra donde está solamente la carpeta de Java-Proyect?

Nota: disculpen tanto texto quería ser lo más claro posible.

Comment: Ahí esta bien. Git Tiene una  opción para separar diferentes versiones en ramas diferentes. Master es una rama. Lo puedes notar porque la url dice tree/master

Comment: no se si al momento de escribir git push escribas el origen de la rama como git push origin <nombre de rama> asi lo hago en un proyecto que tengo cuando solo quiero subir ami rama

Comment: @JDEscobarQuezada Eso es mas para especificar a que rama enviar el push.

Comment: La forma mas simple, siempre, es al reves.. inicias un repo en github, haces un clone del repo, y despues empiezas a trabajar sobre el.. y te ahorras los mil comandos que tuviste que escribir...

Comment: Gracias es como ustedes dice al parecer mi github está configurada para almacenar en la rama máster, y para cambiarla había que ejecutar: git config --global init.defaultBranch main
Y posteriormente en el git push en vez de colocar máster al final era colocar main.